# How to make plesk subdomain reachable

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, plesk

I'm pretty new to the Plesk AdminPanel. I own a Domain called riggiramone.ch. For a friend's project I'm trying to set Wordpress up on the subdomain mugi.riggiramone.ch. I did set up the subdomain and made it point at a subfolder of httpdocs (httpdocs/mugi). Then I have installes wordpress via the Plesk-own tool there.

My problem is that the subdomain mugi.riggiramone.ch is not reachable! I don't know why, I checked all the permissions.

Is there anything I did forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using external DNS server and due to that you are getting this issue. I will suggest you please check your main domain DNS zone and update the correct "A" record for your sun-domain and once you update it correctly you will not get any issues with your sub-domain.